# JS libraries to create a Google Consumer Barometer-like data map?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

What are some javascript libraries or widgets that can generate a data map like the one used in the Google Consumer Barameter here: http://www.consumerbarometer.com/#?app=explore

I'm interested specifically in the data map that shows the hierarchy as a series of linked nodes on nested rings - (and what is that type of map called?)

Answer (score 2):

D3 is a JavaScript library which allows you to draw data-driven graphs: http://d3js.org/

But there are a lot more to discover:

- http://selection.datavisualization.ch/
- http://www.elisa-dbi.co.uk/blog/38-tools-for-beautiful-data-visualisations/

Pick your favorite and start coding

### Update

I am not sure how the type of graph is called, but the term you are looking for may be one of those:

- Reingold–Tilford Tree: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550
- Ring Cluster: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/cluster.html

Comment: Thanks - that's a lot of possibilities! Do you know if any specifically does that type of graph? I guess if I knew what that graph was called I could narrow it down faster.